# Why home folder on different partition

Tags: home-directory

What is the rationale behind having a seperate partition for home folder?

I get it for SWAP space but I prefer to use all of my disk size for root(`/`) except SWAP and boot.

This way I can utilize all disk space no matter what folder my programs are installed.

But seeing that installer is suggesting a different partition makes me think why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether to have the `/home` directory on a different Partition or not,
is totally up to You.
However, it is good practice to separate user data from System Data.

### Pros of Partition Separation:

- Safety: assuming You accidentally corrupted the system (Panic),
  You can safely reinstall the OS, while keeping the `/home` partition and its data intact.
- You can literally redirect the `/home` partition to point to a (New) separate storage device.
- Users downloading or saving big files cannot jam the system due to exhausting the Storage Space.
- Partial Encryption: You can encrypt one partition with a passphrase,
  while leaving the other one accessible.

### Cons of Partition Separation

- slight read-write speed reduction. (negligible)
- running out of memory on one partition yet the storage device is not full.
   This often means manually moving things from one partition the other.

### Side Note:

In case You dislike Physical / Manual Partitioning of the Storage Device,
You can use a Logical Volume Manager (LVM) approach instead, which provides dynamic resizing of the Partitions when the need arises.

Comment: Agree except for 1 thing: /home is not user data. /home/$USER/{directories}/ is user data ( and it is adjustable by editing `.config/user-dirs.dir`. /home should be on the bootable disk. If the system does not spin the 2nd disk up in time it might have unwanted results so /home with config can be a partition but should be on the same disk as /.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks A Lot for the clarification. In some cases, (e.g hosting services), the ability to expand a storage device often comes in handy. With `/home` directory on it's own partition, it is possible to shift it to a totally separate (bigger) storage device, by editing the `UUID`s  in `/etc/fstab` file to specify mandatory devices during booting, and those that can be mounted later on. When the separate `/home` partition is, lets say commented out, the default behavior will be to include it as part of  the `/` partition.